# Rails layout on controller not working but on method it works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, controller

I created my own layout 'standard.html.erb' under the views/layouts folder. I created the following controller:

```
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :initialize


  # layout 'standard'

  def initialize
      @root = '/'
  end

  def home()
    render layout: "standard"
  end

end
```

This -> `layout 'standard'`  is not working for the view

This -> `render layout: "standard"`  works for the home view

I read on internet that the first one should also work. Can't figure out why it is not working.

Comment: Where do you put it?

Comment: Please edit the question clearly. It seems you commented `layout 'standard'`

Comment: you should really avoid naming the method `initialize`, you may override the object's creation etc...

Comment: @Pavan: Actually I commented that line because it was not working.

Answer (score 1):

You have overridden `initialize` method!. The logic to add layouts sits in the original `initialize` method of AbstractController. You need to rename this method and all should work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that, You are not followed method naming conversion properly. You are using `before_filter :initialize`. `:initialize` is for setting properties to object while creating any new object.

Try change name `initialize` to `init` and you are done.